# Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<WebElement> to WebElement in eclipse

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

My code is as below. when i am executing it its giving me error as:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<WebElement> to WebElement
```

at `Learning_Selenium.Selenium_Class.main(Selenium_Class.java:13)`

Let me know if any solution is there. Thanks in advance...

```
package Learning_Selenium;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Selenium_Class {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
         driver.get("http://google.com");
         System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
         WebElement element = driver.findElements(By.name("q"));
         element.sendKeys("Cheese\n");
         element.submit();
         driver.close();
     }
 }
```

Comment: Why do you think that you can convert list to element? List is a collection. Same as converting a book (list of characters) to a single character.

Answer (score 3):

`FindElements` returns a collection of elements.  What you need to do is use the singular `"FindElement"` to get a single instance of an element to work with.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the basic Webdriver concepts. When you are searching for a single element- like a single button that has to be clicked on, you use the `findElement( )` , along with a locator mechanism, to find that element.

For example-

```
WebElement ele1= driver.findElement(By.name("btn1"));
```

or in Python

```
ele1= driver.find_element_by_id('btn1')
```

You use the `findElements( )` method, when you have to find a list of elements. We often use it when there are multiple instances of a web element and you need to find all of them.

For example, if I need to get all the hyperlinks in a webpage, I can get it by
using the `findElements()` method and searching for the anchor tag.

```
WebElement ele2 = driver.findElements(By.tagname("a"));
```

Now, since this would return multiple elements,you will again get an exception as above. We would need a placeholder, that holds multiple elements. So we define the Web Element to of `List` type (in both Java and Python)

In Java

```
List<WebElement> list1= driver.findElements(By.tagname("a"));
```

In Python

```
list_webele = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
```

Hope this helps you in understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `driver.findElement(By.name("q"))` instead of `driver.findElements(By.name("q"))` when searching for single web element.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `findElements` method which will return the list of elements. Where you should use `findElement` method which return single webElement

Your code should be

```
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get array of elements in single element, so compiler throwing an exception.

Try:

```
package Learning_Selenium;
 import org.openqa.selenium.By;
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
 import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
 public class Selenium_Class {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
       driver.get("http://google.com");
       System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
       WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
       element.sendKeys("Cheese\n");
       element.submit();
       driver.close();

}
```

When you use `driver.findElements()` it means it will get all webElements which  argument finds in this query, if you tend to get all element then use :

```
List<<WebElement>> element = driver.findElements(By.name("q"));
```

this will get all elements stored in array.